# Python datetime: strftime() codes for decimal numbers

Tags: python, datetime

Why does it give error?

```py
>>> an = datetime.datetime.now(); an
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 8, 22, 52, 19, 256487)
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(an, '%-d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.datetime.strftime(an, '%-d')
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Based on this sources ([sources1](https://strftime.org/), [sources2](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)) I expected **"8"**

Comment: It works on mine. What's your Python version?

Comment: Please try this.

datetime.datetime.strftime(an, '%#d')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [page you linked](https://strftime.org/) says:

> The Python docs contain all the format codes that the C standard (1989
>   version) requires, and these work on all platforms with a standard C
>   implementation. Note that the 1999 version of the C standard added
>   additional format codes. These include codes for non-zero-padded
>   numbers, that can be obtained by appending a dash (-) (UNIX) or hash
>   (#) (Windows) after the percent (%) sign.

So, this works on Linux:

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(an, '%-d')
```

and this works on Windows:

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(an, '%#d')
```

Interestingly enough, I see no mention of either of them in [Python strftime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). The whole feature may as well be unintentional in Python.